# How to make mupdf automatically refresh a document

Tags: pdf, evince

Upon opening a pdf in `evince` and then making a change to that document (recompiling it in LaTeX), `evince` will automatically refresh to the latest version of the document.

`mupdf` however does not do this: it keeps showing the version I originally opened.
The latest version can be loaded with the `r` command, but is there a way to make `mupdf` behave like `evince` in that respect?
The manual doesn’t mention this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Poke `mupdf` with a `HUP` signal after the document changes (e.g. after recompiling it, or use `entr` or something to note the filesystem change)

```
pkill -HUP mupdf
```

or with more complication one might [write an open-or-signal-`mupdf` script](https://github.com/thrig/scripts/blob/master/misc/mopen).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Since I’m using latexmk (but didn’t mention it in the question), I now found this answer, which is exactly what I was looking for: https://superuser.com/questions/707483/how-do-i-use-latexmk-with-mupdf-as-the-pdf-previewer

Comment: Looks like the user's GitHub account gets deleted, but the script can be found at a fork of the repository https://github.com/wangfuli217/scripts/blob/master/misc/mopen

Answer (score 4):

Adding a little to thrig's answer, this is what I came up with:

```
f=file.pdf; mupdf $f & while inotifywait -e close_write $f; do pkill -HUP mupdf; done
```

This will open a pdf file with mupdf and refresh whenever the pdf is written to.

the idea to use inotify came from [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/181543/943048)

Comment: An alternative is [`when-changed`](https://pypi.org/project/when-changed/) ■ I wrap this into a shell script and make a few improvements: https://gist.github.com/user202729/d1c0435b79faa94faee610a244a3610d

Answer (score 0):

Here's mine:

```
#!/usr/bin/fish

set f $argv[1]
mupdf $f &
set mu_pid $last_pid
while true
    inotifywait --event close_write $f &
    set in_pid $last_pid
    wait --any $mu_pid $in_pid
    if not jobs --query $mu_pid
        exit 0
    end
    kill -HUP $mu_pid
end
```

It only refreshes the specific PID of the instance of mupdf whose file was actually changed, rather than all instances.